# High "System" CPU Usage during laptop idle or sleep, found to be a process called "Unknown"

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu, cpu-usage

Recently, everytime my laptop goes on modern sleep or is left idle for a bit (screen saver turns on), the fan goes crazy. I suspect my CPU is spiking, and sure enough, I caught a glimpse of "System" in task manager with a high CPU each time I log back in. It dies down almost right away though.

So, according to another post, I installed Windows Performance Recorder and recorded my CPU as I put my laptop to modern sleep. Upon analyzing the graphs, I see that a process called "System (4)" is taking up the CPU usage and causing my fan to go berserk. Upon expanding, I see that the CPU usage is attributed to an "Unknown" process. How should I go about debugging/fixing this?

As you can see in the below picture, that spike and drop in CPU usage matches the time points when I put my laptop to modern sleep and when I wake it back up and log in. Under System (4), "Unknown" takes up 11.67% of CPU.

[image]

Comment: Do you by chance have Modern Standby on? If you do there is an active ongoing high priority effort at Microsoft to identify general issues with Modern Standby but it requires submitting diagnostic information. (If your issue is linked we probably won't be able to help you solve it).

Comment: @Ramhound I see - I do have modern standby on; however I've always had it on and this issue only started happening recently (like yesterday). I imagine it is linked to this feature though so perhaps I just have to wait and see. Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1475685-windows-modern-standby-bug-reporting/) explains the process to collect diagnostic information

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a root cause?